# Ошибка при роботе с объектами: переменная player перезаписывается переменной box

Tags: javascript

```
    var playGround = document.getElementById('playGround');        
    var objects = [];

    var GameObject = {
        name: 'GameObject',
        Transform: {
            Scale: [0, 0],
            Location: [0, 0],
            Rotation: 0,
            Sprite: 'none',
        },
    };

    var Create = {
        Object: function(obj) {
            objects.push(obj);
            playGround.innerHTML += "<div class='gameObject " + obj.name + "'></div>";
        },
    };

    var player = GameObject;
    player.name = 'player';
    var box = GameObject;
    box.name = 'box';

Create.Object(player);
Create.Object(box);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде переменные `player` и `box` ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

```
function makeGameObject() {
  return {
    name: 'GameObject',
    Transform: {
        Scale: [0, 0],
        Location: [0, 0],
        Rotation: 0,
        Sprite: 'none',
    },
  };
}

var player = makeGameObject();
player.name = 'player';
var box = makeGameObject();
box.name = 'box';
```